# How do I disable tomcat caching? I'm having weird static file problems

Tags: tomcat, cache, web-server

How do I prevent tomcat from caching? I have css and basic html files that I load and use via ajax, and unless I restart tomcat, the changes do not seem to reflect. Different machines, different browsers, and I don't receive the updated files.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might have to delete the application cache folder in `/work/Catalina/localhost` after changing the `cachingAllowed` flag.

Configuration can be introduced in `server.xml` as

```xml
    <Context className="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext"
                     cachingAllowed="false"
                     charsetMapperClass="org.apache.catalina.util.CharsetMapper"
                     cookies="true" 
                     reloadable="false" 
                     wrapperClass="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper">
            </Context>
```

Comment: +1 I completely forgot to mention that in my original answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Works.

Comment: LOL... where's the love?

Comment: Where do i change the `chachingAllowed` tag?

Comment: Got a warning from Tomcat 8 when starting: Setting property `cachingAllowed` to `false` did not find a matching property.

Comment: This answer is now super out-of-date, for anyone reading, and is no longer really correct (for Tomcat 5+)

Answer (score 18):

For Tomcat 8 / Tomcat 9 properties should be added in conf/context.xml as follows

```
<Context>
  <Resources antiResourceLocking="false" cachingAllowed="false" />
  ...
</Context>
```

You might have to delete the application cache folder in /work/Catalina/localhost after changing the `cachingAllowed` flag. Also clear the cache of IntelliJ IDEA (if you use it to run Tomcat):

```
Mac:     /Users/{:user}/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea{:version}/tomcat/  
Linux:   /home/{:user}/.IntelliJIdea{:version}/system/tomcat/
Windows: C:\Users\{:user}\.IntelliJIdea{:version}\system\tomcat\
```

See [Apache Tomcat 9 Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/resources.html) for other parameters.

Comment: antiResourceLocking on <Resources>-Tag is definitively wrong for tomcat 8

Comment: This isn't correct for tomcat 7, either. "Setting property 'antiResourceLocking' to 'false' did not find a matching property." ... "Setting property 'cachingAllowed' to 'false' did not find a matching property."

Comment: @Amalgovinus for Tomcat 7 see [Zalumon's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/451736/313654).

Comment: @Amalgovinus did you resolve your issue? I have same problem in tomcat7, what did you do?

Comment: I never got the property to work.. but I'm pretty sure my cache was an unrelated deployment issue :( user error

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem in Tomcat 7 and the reason was that I had antiResourceLocking set to true (it sounded like a good idea...).

According to the docs ( http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html ):

> Please note that setting this to true has some side effects, including
>   the disabling of JSP reloading in a running server: see Bugzilla
>   37668.

In my case it even caused plain static text files to be cached.

So, in summary, at least for rapid development I had to use:

```
antiResourceLocking="false"
cachingAllowed="false"
```

Comment: Where do I add this exactly? If I put in conf/context.xml it gives me "did not find a matching property" for each of them...

Comment: As attributes of the context element.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked this documentation: [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) ?

> `cacheMaxSize` -- Maximum size of the
>   static resource cache in kilobytes. If
>   not specified, the default value is
>   10240 (10 megabytes).
>
> `cacheTTL` --
>   Amount of time in milliseconds between
>   cache entries revalidation. If not
>   specified, the default value is 5000
>   (5 seconds).
>
> `cachingAllowed` -- If
>   the value of this flag is true, the
>   cache for static resources will be
>   used. If not specified, the default
>   value of the flag is true.

These parameters are the same for Tomcat 5.5 and Tomcat 6.0.

Comment: I set cachingAllowed to false and cacheTTL to 1000 in my appcontext.xml, and I STILL can't get file not to cache. Worse yet, it's caching across tomcat restarts.

Comment: Then it's gotta be from browser cache