# How to disable cache of Apache Front of my Tomcat?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, cache

I put it at the end of `httpd.conf` and nothing changed:

```
#Initialize mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Please check this thread http://serverfault.com/questions/40205/how-do-i-disable-tomcat-caching-im-having-weird-static-file-problems it may solves your problem

Comment: @CaptainLinux in my `server.xml`where i put the code ?

Comment: First using firebug or similar see what headers come to your browser. Are you sure it's apache httpd that is caching?

Comment: @Fredi when i see my headers i see is not httpd that is caching

Comment: So the caching happens client side (browser)? What headers do your apache send to the browser?